# Loading bitmaps causes outOfMemory in my app

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I'm struggling with memory leak in my Android application. I read milion articles, but still memory is leaking and finally ending. To be more detailed: I have 3 activities which contain grid of image views. All image view contains bitmap from file. Of course I load those bitmaps in small size (using options.inSampleSize). In addition I use kind o cache (class with static map contains bitmaps and its filenames to avoid necessity of loading the same bitmaps from files more than one time) :

```
 public class PhotoCache {
    private static Map<String, Bitmap> photos = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
    public static void addPhoto(String key, Bitmap val) {
        photos.put(key, val);
    }

    public static Bitmap getPhoto(String key) {
        return photos.get(key);
    }

    public static boolean containsPhoto(String key) {
        return photos.containsKey(key);
    }
 }
```

Unfortunately when I move from one activity to another and load more bitmaps from device the memory use is growing very fast, and after about 30 steps (move from one activity to another) there is outOfMemory exception raised.

-> I think that the best thing I can do is recycling bitmaps in onPause methods of my activities and fragments, but then application crashes when I click on back button, because bitmaps which were in use by earlier activity are recycled. I'm looking for some solution for that. Maybe I should load bitmaps in onResume method? Or block clicking the back button more than x (3-5) times? [I don't want to use some ready bitmap solutions and frameworks like Glide or similar.]

Comment: I think that the cache is a problem. You should not store bitmaps, that you don't use now in memory.

Comment: also recycling onPause and loading onResume probably is a good solution. Also I don't see a single reason for you not to reuse code (of other people) by using already super optimized and fast libraries like Glide.

Comment: One more issue is static variables, it have a lifecycle until the application is terminated, so that GC won't work on static variables. You should be very careful while using static variables.

Comment: I thought that cache can be a problem, but when I turned it off, memory was leaking faster, because it loads a lot of bitmaps from disk more often than when I wasn't using cache. I have to try using recycling in onPause, but I doubt if it will work. I know that static variable is not the best solution but in my case cache (implemented on static map) meet the requirements and doesn't have bad impact on memory.